# php file upload missing line break

Tags: php, upload, line-breaks

I have an excel file with data in several columns I want to upload with php (Mac 10.8.2, office2011).

After many detours with decoding issues I ended up with opening the excel file in word, converting to text, copiing into TextEdit and saving as utf-8.

Uploading with `file($myFile);` works fine, but `$medienarray = file($myFile);
print_r($medienarray);` shows that all line breaks are deleted.

But if I manually delete the line breaks in the TextEdit file and type them again, they are recognized after a new upload.

I tried replacing `"\r"` with `"\n"` with a regex:

```
preg_replace('/\r/','/\n/',$medienarray[0],-1,&$anzahl);
```

It shows 20 replacements with no effect.

There are too many data lines to replace all line breaks manually.

Uploading any other text files not created from an excel file work without any line break problems

Comment: Can you show us a line from your $myFile?

Comment: Problem solved: I opened the csv file in BBEdit, saved it as utf-8 with cr/lf-line breaks. Import works fine now with 'CSV WITH DATA' . I had to add a blank columnn to the left of my Excel table to give place for the id field in PHPMyAdmin. Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing \r with \r\n and not just \n.

See here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#In_programming_languages

Answer (score 0):

PHP  need for a newline "\r\n" not only "\r" or "\n". See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#In_programming_languages)